# Pushing a constant one byte at a time

Tags: x86

I'm trying to experiment around with x86 assembly to learn more about it. I'm spawning a shell and I want to push "/bin/sh" onto the stack but I want to do it one byte at a time and I'm not sure if this is even possible. For example, say the string is 0x11223344. I can do..

```
PUSH 0x11223344
```

I want the same the same functionality but instead of pushing the whole constant at once, couldn't I do...

```
PUSH 0x11
PUSH 0x22
PUSH 0x33
PUSH 0x44
(little endian order)
```

I've tried to PUSH 0x44 first but it still isn't working for me. My shell spawns if I push the whole string at once but not if I do it one byte at a time. Is this even possible? (Ignore the fact that there's no terminating char, I purposely didn't add it in my question because that's not the issue)

Comment: No, you can push a word at the shortest.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't do it with a longer push? I'm curious what is compelling you to do it individually.

Comment: No reason. Just trying to see what's possible or not. I did find out that I can in fact PUSH those values but they're not arranged the way i think they are on the stack. I 'd like some help figuring out how to arrange the bytes in order though

Comment: The reason why I can push those small values is because x86 has a push instruction for 8 bit immediate. So theoretically I can keep pushing 8 bit immediates to form a 32 immediate which is the same thing as pushing a 32 bit immediate. If this is correct my stack should have the correct value but its npt

Comment: The pushes that take an 8bit immediate sign-extend it to the operand size, there is no 8bit push.